# Why is my own 4-upvote question not appearing in the Unanswered list for the CSS tag?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, unanswered-questions

I just tried clicked on the Unanswered tab when viewing questions within the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag but noticed my own question (which is currently unanswered with 4 upvotes) is missing: [Why do I have to specify a unit identifier (e.g. 'px') when passing 0 as the only argument into the calc() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829919/why-do-i-have-to-specify-a-unit-identifier-e-g-px-when-passing-0-into-the-c).

[image: CSS Listing Example]

Comment: The description of `Unanswered` are questions with no upvoted answers.

Comment: I see. Any reason my own question isn't appearing in the CSS Unanswered list? I've heavily modified the question to remove the CSS3 tag list part.

Comment: I removed my answer because your edit made it no longer valid. :/

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But I **do** see your question listed, on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?sort=unanswered, as well as on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3?sort=unanswered:

[image: screenshot with question listed]

There have been some reports about queries going awol *sometimes*. They are then cached for a while, returning incomplete or even empty results. The only remedy right now is: wait a little while. It is probably caching.

Comment: Odd. I guess I'll accept this as I can now also see the answer again.